# 高トラフィック時における tcpdump の使い方について

Tags: linux, tcpdump

【環境】: CentOS or Ubuntu

高トラフィック時にどこから攻撃が来ているか等をiptablesのハッシュリミットを用いて対策しています。
こちらで決めた閾値を超えたsrcipはログを取るようにしています。

似たようなことになるかと思いますが、tcpdumpだけでリアルタイムにどこからアクセス（攻撃元）が来ているかどうかを判別することは可能でしょうか？

普通にtcpdump -i IF名 オプションで実行しても、どれが攻撃元かを判別するのは難しいと思います。

1分間（特に時間指定はいりませんが）に異常なアクセス（他のsrcipに比べて大量のアクセス）があるようなホストだけをしぼってtcpdumpさせるような技（オプションまたは手法）をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

不可能であるようならば、一言ムリと教えて頂くだけでも幸いです。

Comment: tcpdumpを使おうと思った理由はなんですか？SYN FLOODなどアプリケーション側では知ることができないアタックを検出したい、とかでしょうかね？思いつくのは(IP, ステート,その他いろいろ)のタプルをSpark Streamingに流し、Maxmind DBでIPからASN, ISP,地域の取得をする。得られた各種属性から、各種DoS指標を１分ごとに集計する。上位NのIPをアタックとしてブロックする、というのはいかがでしょう。

Comment: トラフィックに関して、設定している閾値を超えた場合にアラートが出るようになっております。アラートが出たら、対象の（高トラフィックの原因となっている）srcipを制限したいのです。その対象となるsrcipを発見する方法として、どうしてもiptables以外の方法で検知したいのです。そこで思いついたのがtcpdumpでどうにかして取得できるんではないか？という淡い思いで質問させて頂いた次第でございます。

Answer (score 1):

Linuxでサクッと確認したいなら、
tcptrackやiftopなど。

ちゃんとやるならnetflowとかsflowとかですね。
http://labs.gree.jp/blog/2015/12/15515/

あとはIDSですかね。

> 1分間（特に時間指定はいりませんが）に異常なアクセス（他のsrcipに比べて大量のアクセス）があるようなホストだけをしぼってtcpdumpさせるような技（オプションまたは手法）をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

ありません。